# create alias for existing hostnames

Tags: windows, windows-8, dns, hosts, alias

the question has been asked numerous times but I cannot find a clear answer.
I have a database on Azure:

```
gtxxxxxxx.database.windows.net
```

however, to make things more easy (I hate typing) I would like to shorten that to `gt`.

Such a thing can be done through the hosts file BUT!

> gtxxxxxxx.database.windows.net

has a dynamic IP...... Which actually DOES change from time to time. So how can I create an alias? (I am using Windows 8.1 Enterprise)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find any solution other than using a DNS server. Which is a bit too much trouble to make something easy. So i simply used Authotkey en made it replace de character-combination `gtxxx` with `gtxxxxxxx.database.windows.net`. Good enough.

Answer (score 1):

Well. Apparently what you're asking for isn't that trivial as it seems. Two options I can think of to consider.

**DNS Server**

For a reason like yours I don't think it's worth it (yet you can try if you want to learn something).

**Batch/PowerShell Script**

You can think of simple script that will resolve `gtxxxxxxx.database.windows.net` through DNS and then map IP address to `gt` on OS startup. Still, this can be tricky if IP changes during your work - hosts file won't change until next boot.
You can also think of a simple service in VB.NET or C# that will lookup `gtxxxxxxx.database.windows.net` through DNS from time to time and if necessary, change hosts file.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like all you need is text expansion, check out Breevy or something similiar: http://www.16software.com/breevy/
Breevy is a text expander for Windows that helps you type faster and more accurately by allowing you to abbreviate long words and phrases -- saving you time and money.

Simply define an abbreviation for a longer piece of text, like eml for JohnDoe@email.com.